# Eclipse disable "Run in Background"

Tags: java, eclipse

eclipse (3.7) does provide a nice abstract class [Job](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/runtime/jobs/Job.html) for running tasks in a separate jobs. Using this opens a dialog with three buttons, "Run in Background", "Chancel" and "Details".

Is there any implementation or even a simple setting to remove the button "Run in Background" (and the checkbox "Always run in background")? Or do I have to provide my own implementation for this?

**Update - Workaround**

A co-worker had an idea, this workaround seems to be a good alternative.

```
new ProgressMonitorDialog(this.getPage().getShell()).run(true, true, new IRunnableWithProgress() {
  @Override
  public void run(IProgressMonitor monitor) throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException {
     monitor.beginTask("Konfiguration speichern...", IProgressMonitor.UNKNOWN);
     // Do something here
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dialog is display by the Eclipse progress manager `org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressManager`. It is not really practical to replace this.

The dialog is not displayed at all if `setUser(false)` is called on the `Job`.

Comment: yes, but I do wanna see the ProgressManager just without the "Run in background", is this possible? Or do I have to implement everything by my own. Progressbar with separate Job etc...

Comment: No it is not possible without replacing the progress manager which is not practical.